# My firebase authentication window self closes

Tags: facebook, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I'm trying to implement firebase simple-login, but somehow I'm making it not so simple.

I'm following http://angularfire.com/documentation.html#authentication

I've got:

```
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-simple-login.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.3.0/angularfire.js"></script>
```

in my index.html and

```
  var ref = new Firebase("https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/");
  angularFireAuth.initialize(ref, {scope: $scope, name: "user"});

$scope.login = function() {
  angularFireAuth.login("facebook");
};
```

in my controller with my firebaseurl in place.

If I have not enabled facebook in firebase forge, I get Sorry, an error occurred: The specified authentication type is not enabled for this Firebase.

However, when I enable it, the login window opens and self closes after a second or so. There's a message there, but it's so brief I can't get a single word.

Any ideas of what might be wrong?

EDIT:
I hadn't set my app up properly on facebook with correct app ID and Secret. It works like a charm now.

Comment: Probably nothing is wrong. Are there any errors? Are you logged in after the window closes? If you want the window not to close immediately, try logging out of facebook before you authenticate--if logged in, it will pop up OAuth, see that you are logged in, and auto-close (this is SOP for OAuth in a separate window)

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. I'm not getting any errors, at least not in the console. Regardless of browser/ and facebook/twitter etc and being logged in or not, it all doesn't seem to matter. The window has this "waiting for auth.firebase.com" down left and then it's gone after a second. My user is null afterwards.
Cheers

Comment: If this is still occurring for you, go ahead and reach out to support@firebase.com and we can look into what might be impacting your specific application.

Comment: My setup on facebook and with the id/secret wasn't right. Thank you guys for trying to help me.